# In the Yii2 advanced app template, how can I render a view from the frontend from the root of the project?

Tags: php, yii2, xampp

I have been making a yii2 project for a couple of months now and I have recently came to the conclusion that I need to have the main URL for my main page be http://localhost/yii-application/ rather than http://localhost/yii-application/frontend/web/.

I've been trying to set this up today by moving the folders to the base and changing the rules in the URL manager but I can't seem to get this to work.

I've also been trying to replicate the basic Yii2 application to see how it does it but I'm not having a lot of luck there either.

My main view files path that is rendered by http://localhost/yii-application/frontend/web/ is frontend/views/listings/index.php

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Comment: First of all, urls and view template locations are completely independent on each other. When you call `render()` method in your controller's action you can point it pretty much to any file you want. At least as long as php can read that file. To change the url as you've described you should set up an alias in your web server config and make that alias point to the `frontend/web` folder.